# Does Sharepoint/Office365/OneDrive change logs REST API provide any download event for a document?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, onedrive-for-business

I'd like to know if there is any event generated when a document is downloaded (a File on the OneDrive for a user of my Office 365 tenant)
or let me put it this way, a change event or some other indication when the content of a document is accessed/downloaded?

The change events I receive are only for CRUD operations on an item. Is there a way to indicate that a download has been made? Or any field in the Meta data for a document (List item) that would indicate that it was downloaded at a certain timestamp or the number of downloads for that item?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auditing for Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties is not available for SharePoint Online in Office 365 for enterprises.

Comment: Is there any official word on it? Could you please point me to it?

Comment: Can you please tell me if the API provides IP information for the user/app doing the actions, in the change events received?